# Is there a weaker version of Yoneda?

Tags: category-theory

Let $A,B$ be objects of a locally small category $\mathcal{C}$ such that $\operatorname{Hom}(D,A)\hookrightarrow \operatorname{Hom}(D,B)$ for every object $D$ in a natural way. In what situations can we conclude from this some relations on $A$ and $B$? For example, naively, I would like to have $A\hookrightarrow B$ (a mono).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems like you have in mind an isomorphism version of Yoneda, but the usual version already implies that natural maps $\text{Hom}(-, A) \to \text{Hom}(-, B)$ (not necessarily natural isos) are the same thing as maps $f : A \to B$. Then it's an exercise to see that the corresponding natural maps are all injective iff $f$ is a mono; this is just an exercise in unraveling the definition of a mono. I would not call this stronger or weaker than any version of the Yoneda lemma since neither implies the other.

(It is *not* true that the corresponding natural maps are all surjective iff $f$ is an epi; you get a much stronger condition, namely being a split epi.)

Comment: In fact being epic is also encoded by injectivity on the level of hom sets: $f : A \to B$ is epic iff $f^* : \hom(B,C) \to \hom(A,C)$ is *injective* for all $C$.